# Finding bug in simple add function

Tags: c, function, addition

This was asked in an interview. "There is a bug in the below function, what is it?". It is simple add c function and main function calls it. Given some clue -- "Give different set of input values, test and find bug".

```
int add (int x, int y)
{ 
    return x + y;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The problem can be integer overflow occurs if `x+y` is greater than `INT_MAX` or less than `INT_MIN`. So use `long long` as return type.

Comment: +1 of course, do you know an alternative to `long long` for compilers without support for C99?

Comment: You can use `unsigned` if you know that at least one of the numbers are greater than zero.

Comment: "at least one of the numbers are greater than zero", no, `unsigned long x = -5 + 2` will fail, do you mean if the greater abs value is > 0?

Comment: No, I mean it wouldn't cause an overflow. We can evaluate the value even in your case. If the most significant bit in the return value is `0` do noting. If it is `1` , then find it's compliment.